# Black screen after installing Ubuntu 11.10 on new pc

Tags: 11.10, drivers, xorg, video, radeon

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

After installing Ubuntu on my fresh desktop, the Ubuntu loading screen shortly appears and then I get a black screen. After that the screen is split into two.

The image begins at the middle and then continues over the left half of the screen. I have a Radeon 6850HD with dual monitors connection, has it something to do with this?

When booting in failsafe mode, I get a message that Ubuntu failed to load failsafe video drivers. I am able to start a live session though. So I guess it loads the wrong drivers upon booting from hd. I think maybe editing the `xorg.conf` file could help, but until now I did not succeed.

Comment: Are you able to boot into recovery mode? You need to install the proprietary drivers (use `sudo jockey-text`)

Comment: Sometimes I can boot into the system, sometimes not. So yesterday i installed the property drivers, it worked well but today I cannot boot again, the same problems. What does your command do exactly?

Comment: it allows you to install the proprietary drivers from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment (I don't know why) so I answer as far as I had similar problem with Ubuntu 12 and my nvidia card. What I did is to install the alternate distro and when I had to reboot I chose the recovery mode, set up network, return to main menu and finally update whatever I could.